# How to avoid lost focus of TextBox when click a button in wpf?

Tags: wpf, textbox

[image]

Now the cursor is focusing in the TextBox. If i click on the the Button (RemoveLostFocus),The TextBox's Lost focus event get fired. But What i need is , Lost Focus event of TextBox should not fire. is there any way to do so ?.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtUserName.Focus();
    }

private void UserName_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtUserName.Text.Length < 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UserName should not be empty");
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
                    anotherWindow.Show();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried some validation and it will prompt as message window. If I click button which is called Cancel. That validation part is executing.

Comment: When should this be possible `Text.Length < 0`?

Comment: When i focus to another TextBox which is not mentioned here

Comment: AFAIK `Text.Length` never can't be lesser then 0.

Comment: sorry, It is Text.Length < 1

Answer (score 8):

You will want to use the `FocusManager` attached properties to apply the focus to the `TextBox` when the `Button` focus changes

Example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="txtbx" />
    <Button Content="Click Me!" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtbx}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

With this solution the The `TextBox` will always be focused even when the `Button` is pressed and the `TextBox` `LostFocus` event will not be fired

Comment: +1 that (on the container) + `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` - the only solution that actually works

Comment: My next question, what if you want to do the same exact thing as this (with TextBox and Button), but the Textbox is on a custom control, and the button is on the window that is containing that custom control?

Answer (score 1):

you could Set Focusable="False" on the Button. here is a link of the answer [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010826/is-it-possible-to-click-a-button-without-ever-losing-focus-on-a-textbox)

Answer (score -1):

Set [Focusable Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.focusable.aspx)

```
<Button Focusable="False" />
```

Comment: i used your code even though,Lostfocus fired. I will edit my which my real scenario.

Comment: With `this.Close()` in your button handler you raise the `LostFocus` event. What do you want to close?

Comment: To navigate to another window.

Comment: But if you leave the window TextBox will lose the focus as well. You can't avoid this.

Comment: If i use this.Hide() instead of this.Close(). It is working. When i have only one window, this time i use this code(this.Hide()) means , the application is running not end. is this correct way of approach ?

Comment: I would say this is not a good design. Don't try to prevent events to be raised to reach your goal. But I don't understand why not instantly validate your TextBox. I think this would be what the user is expecting.

Answer (score -1):

In the Click-Event of you Button you can do something like

```
this.textBox.Focus();
```

If your lostfocus-method looks like this:

```
private void UserName_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){ ... }
```

you can prevent the lostfocus with the following code:

```
this.textBox.LostFocus -= UserName_LostFocus;
```

Comment: Please see my edited code. when i click cancel button TextBox's lost focus event get fired and the logic in the lost focus event is executing.But i don't want so.