# How to avoid lost focus of TextBox when click a button in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

please refer below link to understand my issue.

in this link the issue is for WPF but in may case it is Asp.net

[How to avoid lost focus of TextBox when click a button in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133005/how-to-avoid-lost-focus-of-textbox-when-click-a-button-in-wpf)

How to solve this issue in asp.net.

```
private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Responce.Redirect("test.aspx");

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Web application is much different from the WPF application because of client side processing and server side processing. You can achieve this with javascript.

You can register a clientscript that focuses on the textbox from the server side code once the processes is done on the server.

```
function setfocus(){
   $('#txt').focus();
}
```

You can register the script as the last sentence in the button event block like this

```
void btnevent(Sender obj, EventArgs e)
{
 ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), 
 "script", 
 "<script language=javascript> setfocus(); </script>");
}
```

This will eject the script at the bottom of the page so that it can be invoked immediately. The setfocus function already written in the javascript block of your asp.net html source.